# ExtJS Gridpanel Column width + forcefit

Tags: extjs, width, gridpanel

I have a gridpanel that i would like to have 2 columns in. I want the first column to have a width of 100 and the second column to fill the remaining width in the gridpanel.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
sensorListPanel = new xg.GridPanel({
    id: 'sensorListPanel',
    region: 'west',
    width: 415,
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit:true,
        //fitcontainer:true
    },
    store: sensorStore,
    cm: new xg.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            width: 120,
            sortable: true
        },
        columns: [
            smSensors,
            {id:'Station',header: "Station", width: 95, dataIndex: 'gml_id'},
            {id:'Description', header: "Description", dataIndex: 'description'}
        ]
    }),
    sm: smSensors,
    columnLines: true,
    title:'Sensors',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting forceFit in viewconfig

```
viewConfig:{forceFit:true}
```

By specifying forceFit:true, non-fixed width columns will be re-proportioned (based on the relative initial widths) to fill the width of the grid.

Comment: When I do that, the columns are divided in 2 and evenly spread out. Please see the code I just posted. Thanks!!!

Comment: remove width from defaults config of column model

Comment: hello MMT,i am try in framework version 5.0.1 but not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use "autoExpandColumn" config which present on Grid.

```
{
    xtype : 'grid',

    cm : //Your Column model Code,

    autoExpandColumn : COLUMN_NAME_FROM_COLUMN_MODEL
}
```

In column model, you can specify width for fixed width columns.